# How do i alert users when they not able to access the server

Tags: javascript

```js
var serviceURL = "http://mywebsite.com/mobile/";

var employees;

$(window).load(function() {
 setTimeout(getEmployeeList, 100);
});

function getEmployeeList() {
 $.getJSON(serviceURL + 'getemployees.php', function(data) {
  $('#employeeList li').remove();
  employees = data.items;
  $.each(employees, function(index, employee) {
   $('#employeeList').append('<li><a href="reportlist.html?id=' + employee.id + '">' +
     '<img src="pics/' + employee.picture + '" class="list-icon"/>' +
     '<p class="line1">' + employee.firstName + ' ' + employee.lastName + '</p>' +
     '<p class="line2">' + employee.title + '</p>' +
     '<span class="bubble">' + employee.reportCount + '</span></a></li>');
  });
  setTimeout(function(){
   scroll.refresh();
  });
 });
}
```

My problem with my script is that any time i try to reach server and it is down  i want my application to be alert people that the server is down for now

Comment: Your question is very unclear. What are you doing? How are you doing it? Is it a webpage / web app?

Comment: Use `$.ajax` instead and check the docs for reacting to an error.

Comment: Use the .fail() handler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var serviceURL = "http://mywebsite.com/mobile/";

var employees;

$(window).load(function() {
 setTimeout(getEmployeeList, 100);
});
// Use the ajaxError method to handle your error 
$(document).ajaxError(function(event, request, settings) {
 //Then you can use the .hide() to hide div alert users for error
 $('#errorserver').hide();
 alert("Error accessing the server");
});

function getEmployeeList() {
//Then you can use the .show() to show loading 
 $('#errorserver').show();
 $.getJSON(serviceURL + 'getemployees.php', function(data) {
  //Then you can use the .hide() 
  $('#errorserver').hide();
  $('#employeeList li').remove();
  employees = data.items;
  $.each(employees, function(index, employee) {
   $('#employeeList').append('<li><a href="reportlist.html?id=' + employee.id + '">' +
     '<img src="pics/' + employee.picture + '" class="list-icon"/>' +
     '<p class="line1">' + employee.firstName + ' ' + employee.lastName + '</p>' +
     '<p class="line2">' + employee.title + '</p>' +
     '<span class="bubble">' + employee.reportCount + '</span></a></li>');
  });
  setTimeout(function(){
   scroll.refresh();
  });
 });
}
```

```html
//Add this div to your html page

  <div id="errorserver"/><img src="image/loading.png" alt="Loading please wait.."></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to handle errors using .fail method:

```
$.getJSON(serviceURL + 'getemployees.php', function(data) {
    // ... your implementation
}).fail(function (err) {
    // ... this callback will be invoked
    // ... in case any error of the server
});
```